# AWS Beanstalk error in browser: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services

I have these errors after deploying a React app code in AWS beanstalk

firefox: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
chrome: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

routes file:

The HTML page shows up but not any of js code.

```
// API Routes
router.use("/api", apiRoutes);

// If no API routes are hit, send the React app
router.use(function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build/index.html"));
});

module.exports = router;
```

here is my html in a build folder

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reactstrap/4.8.0/reactstrap.min.js"/><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton" rel="stylesheet"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel" rel="stylesheet"><title>JeM Labs</title><style>body{background:#add8e6!important}</style><link href="/static/css/main.850921e2.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.f03783df.js"></script></body></html>
```

I cannot figure out why it is not working

[Browser image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYfLq.png)

Comment: I think your server is only serving `index.html` file, but not serving other assets (i.e. main.xxx.css, main.xxx.js etc). Can you access `/static/js/main.f03783df.js` file from you browser. Do you see any errors in the browser inspector's network tab?

Comment: @euvs - See my screenshot when I click on the link to `main.f03783df.js` in the inspector. Its attached to the original comment

Comment: Usually, browsers can infer content-type from the file extension but the response returned is without a file extension. You will need to explicitly set the content-type heading to "text/html" in your response so that the browser can know to parse it as HTML